# How can I use the right mouse button instead of OnMouseDrag?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unityscript

How can I adjust the following script to use the middle mouse button or right mouse button instead of the left mouse button? The script currently uses `OnMouseDown`, `OnMouseUp`, and `OnMouseDrag`.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class FPH_DoorObject_Drag : MonoBehaviour {

/*
 * This script is for doors which can be opened dragging on the screen
 */

public float factor = 2.0f; // How fast will be the movement
public float minRot = 0.0f;
public float maxRot = 90.0f;


public string[] observeKind = new string[] {"Normal", "Closeup"};
public int observeInt = 0; // this variable is used inside of the Editor script

public float secToOserve = 1.3f; // After this amount of seconds the text will reset

public GameObject inGameCamera;
public GameObject closeupCamera;

public bool removeItemWhenUsed;
public string hasBeenUnlockedKey;

public bool canBeObserved;
public AudioClip lockedSound;

public string observMessage_English;
public string observMessage_Italian;
public string observMessage_Spanish;
public string observMessage_German;
public string observMessage_French;
public string observMessage_Japanese;
public string observMessage_Chinese;
public string observMessage_Russian;

public string lockedMessage_English;
public string lockedMessage_Italian;
public string lockedMessage_Spanish;
public string lockedMessage_German;
public string lockedMessage_French;
public string lockedMessage_Japanese;
public string lockedMessage_Chinese;
public string lockedMessage_Russian;

public string wrongItemMessage_English;
public string wrongItemMessage_Italian;
public string wrongItemMessage_Spanish;
public string wrongItemMessage_German;
public string wrongItemMessage_French;
public string wrongItemMessage_Japanese;
public string wrongItemMessage_Chinese;
public string wrongItemMessage_Russian;


public int doorType = 0;
/*
 * A dor can be:
 * " Normally Open " - The door is always open
 * " Locked " - The door is always locked and CAN'T be opened
 * " Need Equipped Object " - The door is locked but can be opened if the player equip an object
 * " Need Activated Key " - The door is locked but can be opened if a PlayerPres key is " 1 " which means true
 */
public string[] doorTypeArray = new string[] {"Normally Open", "Locked", "Need Equipped Object", "Need Activated Key"};
public string neededObject_Name;
public string neededKey;


private Vector3 startRot;
private float startPlayerRot;
private float currRot;
private float playerRot;
private float delta = 0;
private Transform playerTransform;
private bool canbeOpen;
public float openDirection;
private bool hasBeenUnlocked;


void Start(){
    openDirection = -1.0f;

    playerTransform = GameObject.FindWithTag("Player").transform;
    startRot = this.gameObject.GetComponent<Transform>().eulerAngles;
    delta = 0;

    hasBeenUnlocked = FPH_ControlManager.LoadBool(hasBeenUnlockedKey);
    if(hasBeenUnlocked){
        doorType = 0;
    }
}

void Update(){
    if(doorType == 0){
        canbeOpen = true;
    }
    if(doorType == 1){
        canbeOpen = false;
    }
    if(doorType == 2){
        if(FPH_InventoryManager.equippedItem != neededObject_Name && FPH_InventoryManager.equippedItem != "" && FPH_InventoryManager.equippedItem != " "){
            canbeOpen = false;
        }
        if(FPH_InventoryManager.equippedItem == "" || FPH_InventoryManager.equippedItem == " "){
            canbeOpen = false;
        }
        if(FPH_InventoryManager.equippedItem == neededObject_Name){
            canbeOpen = true;
        }
    }
    if(doorType == 3){
        bool boolValue = FPH_ControlManager.LoadBool(neededKey);
        if(boolValue){
            canbeOpen = true;
        }
        else{
            canbeOpen = false;
        }
    }
}

public void OnMouseDown(){
    if(canbeOpen){
        startPlayerRot = playerTransform.eulerAngles.y;
    }
}

public void OnMouseUp(){
    if(doorType == 1){
        StartCoroutine("PrivateLocked");
    }
    if(doorType == 2){
        if(FPH_InventoryManager.equippedItem != neededObject_Name && FPH_InventoryManager.equippedItem != "" && FPH_InventoryManager.equippedItem != " "){
            StartCoroutine("PrivateWrongItem");
        }
        if(FPH_InventoryManager.equippedItem == "" || FPH_InventoryManager.equippedItem == " "){
            StartCoroutine("PrivateLocked");
        }
    }
    if(doorType == 3 && !canbeOpen){
        StartCoroutine("PrivateLocked");
    }

    if(canbeOpen){
        startRot.y = currRot;
        delta = 0;

        if(FPH_InventoryManager.equippedItem == neededObject_Name && !hasBeenUnlocked){
            hasBeenUnlocked = true;
            FPH_ControlManager.SaveBool(hasBeenUnlockedKey, hasBeenUnlocked);
            doorType = 0;

            //Afte we used the item we unequip it
            FPH_InventoryManager.equippedItem = "";
            FPH_InventoryManager.equippedItem_Index = -1;
            if(removeItemWhenUsed){
                FPH_InventoryManager.RemoveInventoryItem(FPH_InventoryManager.equippedItem_Index);
                FPH_InventoryManager.SaveInventory();
            }
        }
    }
}

void OnMouseDrag(){
    if(canbeOpen){
        playerRot = playerTransform.eulerAngles.y;
        delta = (playerRot - startPlayerRot) * openDirection; // openDirection si important or player rotation will be the inverse of door rot
        currRot = (startRot.y + (delta * factor));
        currRot = Mathf.Clamp(currRot, minRot, maxRot); // door rotation can't be bigger or smaller than min and max rot
        transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(startRot.x, currRot, startRot.z);

        if(FPH_InventoryManager.equippedItem == neededObject_Name && !hasBeenUnlocked){
            hasBeenUnlocked = true;
            FPH_ControlManager.SaveBool(hasBeenUnlockedKey, hasBeenUnlocked);
            doorType = 0;

            //Afte we used the item we unequip it
            FPH_InventoryManager.equippedItem = "";
            FPH_InventoryManager.equippedItem_Index = -1;
            if(removeItemWhenUsed){
                FPH_InventoryManager.RemoveInventoryItem(FPH_InventoryManager.equippedItem_Index);
                FPH_InventoryManager.SaveInventory();
            }
        }
    }
}

public void Observe(){
    if(observeInt == 0){
        StartCoroutine("PrivateObserve_Normal");
    }
    if(observeInt == 1){
        StartCoroutine("PrivateObserve_Closeup");
    }
}

IEnumerator PrivateLocked(){
    FPH_LanguageManager.static_observeTextMesh.text = "";
    if(lockedSound){
        GetComponent<AudioSource>().PlayOneShot(lockedSound);
    }

    if(FPH_LanguageManager.gameLanguage == FPH_LanguageManager.LanguagesEnum.English){
        FPH_LanguageManager.static_observeTextMesh.text = lockedMessage_English;
    }
    if(FPH_LanguageManager.gameLanguage == FPH_LanguageManager.LanguagesEnum.Italian){
        FPH_LanguageManager.static_observeTextMesh.text = lockedMessage_Italian;
    }
    if(FPH_LanguageManager.gameLanguage == FPH_LanguageManager.LanguagesEnum.Spanish){
        FPH_LanguageManager.static_observeTextMesh.text = lockedMessage_Spanish;
    }
    if(FPH_LanguageManager.gameLanguage == FPH_LanguageManager.LanguagesEnum.German){
        FPH_LanguageManager.static_observeTextMesh.text = lockedMessage_German;
    }
    if(FPH_LanguageManager.gameLanguage == FPH_LanguageManager.LanguagesEnum.French){
        FPH_LanguageManager.static_observeTextMesh.text = lockedMessage_French;
    }
    if(FPH_LanguageManager.gameLanguage == FPH_LanguageManager.LanguagesEnum.Japanese){
        FPH_LanguageManager.static_observeTextMesh.text = lockedMessage_Japanese;
    }
    if(FPH_LanguageManager.gameLanguage == FPH_LanguageManager.LanguagesEnum.Chinese){
        FPH_LanguageManager.static_observeTextMesh.text = lockedMessage_Chinese;
    }
    if(FPH_LanguageManager.gameLanguage == FPH_LanguageManager.LanguagesEnum.Russian){
        FPH_LanguageManager.static_observeTextMesh.text = lockedMessage_Russian;
    }

    yield return new WaitForSeconds(secToOserve);

    FPH_LanguageManager.static_observeTextMesh.text = "";
}

IEnumerator PrivateWrongItem(){
    FPH_LanguageManager.static_observeTextMesh.text = "";
    if(lockedSound){
        GetComponent<AudioSource>().PlayOneShot(lockedSound);
    }

    if(FPH_LanguageManager.gameLanguage == FPH_LanguageManager.LanguagesEnum.English){
        FPH_LanguageManager.static_observeTextMesh.text = wrongItemMessage_English;
    }
    if(FPH_LanguageManager.gameLanguage == FPH_LanguageManager.LanguagesEnum.Italian){
        FPH_LanguageManager.static_observeTextMesh.text = wrongItemMessage_Italian;
    }
    if(FPH_LanguageManager.gameLanguage == FPH_LanguageManager.LanguagesEnum.Spanish){
        FPH_LanguageManager.static_observeTextMesh.text = wrongItemMessage_Spanish;
    }
    if(FPH_LanguageManager.gameLanguage == FPH_LanguageManager.LanguagesEnum.German){
        FPH_LanguageManager.static_observeTextMesh.text = wrongItemMessage_German;
    }
    if(FPH_LanguageManager.gameLanguage == FPH_LanguageManager.LanguagesEnum.French){
        FPH_LanguageManager.static_observeTextMesh.text = wrongItemMessage_French;
    }
    if(FPH_LanguageManager.gameLanguage == FPH_LanguageManager.LanguagesEnum.Japanese){
        FPH_LanguageManager.static_observeTextMesh.text = wrongItemMessage_Japanese;
    }
    if(FPH_LanguageManager.gameLanguage == FPH_LanguageManager.LanguagesEnum.Chinese){
        FPH_LanguageManager.static_observeTextMesh.text = wrongItemMessage_Chinese;
    }
    if(FPH_LanguageManager.gameLanguage == FPH_LanguageManager.LanguagesEnum.Russian){
        FPH_LanguageManager.static_observeTextMesh.text = wrongItemMessage_Russian;
    }

    yield return new WaitForSeconds(secToOserve);

    FPH_LanguageManager.static_observeTextMesh.text = "";
}

IEnumerator PrivateObserve_Normal(){
    if(FPH_LanguageManager.gameLanguage == FPH_LanguageManager.LanguagesEnum.English){ // If language is ....
        FPH_LanguageManager.static_observeTextMesh.text = observMessage_English; // Set this thext
    }
    if(FPH_LanguageManager.gameLanguage == FPH_LanguageManager.LanguagesEnum.Italian){
        FPH_LanguageManager.static_observeTextMesh.text = observMessage_Italian;
    }
    if(FPH_LanguageManager.gameLanguage == FPH_LanguageManager.LanguagesEnum.Spanish){
        FPH_LanguageManager.static_observeTextMesh.text = observMessage_Spanish;
    }
    if(FPH_LanguageManager.gameLanguage == FPH_LanguageManager.LanguagesEnum.German){
        FPH_LanguageManager.static_observeTextMesh.text = observMessage_German;
    }
    if(FPH_LanguageManager.gameLanguage == FPH_LanguageManager.LanguagesEnum.French){
        FPH_LanguageManager.static_observeTextMesh.text = observMessage_French;
    }
    if(FPH_LanguageManager.gameLanguage == FPH_LanguageManager.LanguagesEnum.Japanese){
        FPH_LanguageManager.static_observeTextMesh.text = observMessage_Japanese;
    }
    if(FPH_LanguageManager.gameLanguage == FPH_LanguageManager.LanguagesEnum.Chinese){
        FPH_LanguageManager.static_observeTextMesh.text = observMessage_Chinese;
    }
    if(FPH_LanguageManager.gameLanguage == FPH_LanguageManager.LanguagesEnum.Russian){
        FPH_LanguageManager.static_observeTextMesh.text = observMessage_Russian;
    }

    yield return new WaitForSeconds(secToOserve); // After " secToOserve " ...

    FPH_LanguageManager.static_observeTextMesh.text = ""; // Reset the text
}

/*
 * We toggle the cameras and  show a text, everything will be reset
 * after " secToOserve "
 */
IEnumerator PrivateObserve_Closeup(){
    inGameCamera.SetActive(false);
    closeupCamera.SetActive(true);
    FPH_ControlManager.canBeControlled = false;

    yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.1f);

    if(FPH_LanguageManager.gameLanguage == FPH_LanguageManager.LanguagesEnum.English){
        FPH_LanguageManager.static_observeTextMesh.text = observMessage_English;
    }
    if(FPH_LanguageManager.gameLanguage == FPH_LanguageManager.LanguagesEnum.Italian){
        FPH_LanguageManager.static_observeTextMesh.text = observMessage_Italian;
    }
    if(FPH_LanguageManager.gameLanguage == FPH_LanguageManager.LanguagesEnum.Spanish){
        FPH_LanguageManager.static_observeTextMesh.text = observMessage_Spanish;
    }
    if(FPH_LanguageManager.gameLanguage == FPH_LanguageManager.LanguagesEnum.German){
        FPH_LanguageManager.static_observeTextMesh.text = observMessage_German;
    }
    if(FPH_LanguageManager.gameLanguage == FPH_LanguageManager.LanguagesEnum.French){
        FPH_LanguageManager.static_observeTextMesh.text = observMessage_French;
    }
    if(FPH_LanguageManager.gameLanguage == FPH_LanguageManager.LanguagesEnum.Japanese){
        FPH_LanguageManager.static_observeTextMesh.text = observMessage_Japanese;
    }
    if(FPH_LanguageManager.gameLanguage == FPH_LanguageManager.LanguagesEnum.Chinese){
        FPH_LanguageManager.static_observeTextMesh.text = observMessage_Chinese;
    }
    if(FPH_LanguageManager.gameLanguage == FPH_LanguageManager.LanguagesEnum.Russian){
        FPH_LanguageManager.static_observeTextMesh.text = observMessage_Russian;
    }

    yield return new WaitForSeconds(secToOserve);

    FPH_LanguageManager.static_observeTextMesh.text = "";

    yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.3f);

    inGameCamera.SetActive(true);
    closeupCamera.SetActive(false);
    FPH_ControlManager.canBeControlled = true;
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OnMouseDown, OnMouseUp, and OnMouseDrag are only made to be used with the left click. What you need to do in order to implement with right click, is to use [Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1)](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetMouseButtonDown.html) and [Input.GetMouseButtonUp(1)](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetMouseButtonUp.html) in order to know the sate of the mouse button.

Something like this :

```
bool dragging = false;
void Update()
{
    if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1))
    {
        yourOnMouseDownFunction();
        dragging = true;
    }
    if(Input.GetMouseButtonUp(1))
    {
        yourOnMouseUpFunction();
        dragging = false;
    }

    if(dragging )
    {
        yourOnMouseDragFunction();
    }
}
```

There are better ways to do this but they will require more code.